# jQuery set focus on autocomplete list element

Tags: jquery

How do I focus on the created autocomplete menu item:

```
 <ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" ...>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-3" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">ONE</a>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-4" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">TWO</a>
<...>
```

I've tried to `$('#ui-id-3').focus();`

Have not effect.
Generaly i mean custom autocomplete:
https://forum.jquery.com/viewImage.do?fileId=14737000004279180&forumGroupId=14737000000003003

Comment: did you place your code onload of the page?

Comment: for experiment my autocompete is default open. i have a link with action $('#ui-id-3').focus();

Comment: it's working well with me. follow this link. http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/Rd9Mb/

Comment: I need this work in autocomplete widget. It is not correct focus, because i can't move cursor on autocomplete elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ],
    autoFocus: true 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bqujj/91/

Comment: Thank you, i now this option. Generaly, i need widget can focus element by typed letter (without filtering). So i started to learn  set focus.

Comment: Another words it is an advanced dropdownlist.